# Superfish Menu Last Item Not 100% In IE

Tags: css, menu, superfish

I have two demo pages here:

http://quiltersrule.com/beta/index.html

http://quiltersrule.com/beta/retail.html

When hovering over "Instructions & Products" as well as "Events", the last child link does not have a full background until you hover over it. The "About Us" is just fine. I have tried messing around with z-index, but this does not seem to be the problem. I have no idea what to do.

All the code and everything should be accessible via View Page Source so I'm not going to try to paste it here.

Edit: Forgot to mention this happens in IE only. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
If the issue is *only* in IE, then an IE specific stylesheet is what you need:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

[Full tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

**Original:**

Looks fine to me (Chrome v27, OS X 10.8):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add it was in IE this was happening.

Comment: *sighs* What version of IE?